# Adding one to matched number in substitution regex

Tags: c++, regex, perl, substitution, addition

I have a file full of C++ code which is a bunch of small functions that return a number. I am trying to replace each number with the number plus one **if** the number is greater than 2. So,

```
int blah() { return 5; }
```

would become

```
int blah() { return 6; }
```

but

```
int blah() { return 1; }
```

would remain the same.

How is this done?

Comment: Are you asking how to edit your source code file?  Or do you want to programmatically alter the return values?  If you are looking to edit your code then an editor that supports regex would probably be able to do the search and replace operation in very short order.

Comment: @MauMen I know how to edit the source file once I know how to write the regex. What I am asking is how to add one to a matched number, so I want to "programmatically alter the return values." And the search and replace of editors cannot do math either.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: Just how many of these little functions are there? Tens? Hundreds?

Comment: @Asaph A little less than an hundred, but why does it matter? Is this another example of people on SO asking for information that has absolutely no bearing on the problem at hand? I think so.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: You can't expect to post code that has such an obvious smell of repetition and get zero comments about it. It sounds like the (fairly obvious) idea of refactoring the code to be less repetitive has already occurred to you and you've moved past it for whatever reason. Maybe you're constrained at what calling code you can modify. Maybe a major refactoring is a tough sell to your manager/co-workers. Whatever the reason, I don't think it's so off-base of me to explore this idea in form of comments on the question. Note that my original comment has been upvoted by our peers.

Comment: @Asaph the code is only as repetitive as it needs to be. The functions are template function specializations for what is as close to a compile time hash table as I can make without bringing in something like gperf.

Comment: Whoo, blind uninformed condemnation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit ugly, but should work:

```
s/\{\s*return\s+(\d+)\s*;\s*\}/$1 > 2 ? "{ return " . ($1 + 1) . "; }" : $&/ge;
```

Comment: It enables you to inline and evaluate ordinary Perl code inside regular expressions.

Comment: Also just for the record, you don't need the `int` casts in there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the number with `[3-9]`. Example:
`/int\s*blah\(\)\s*\{\s*return\s*([3-9]);\s*}/g`

EDIT:

To increase a value in the `$1`, you will need the flag `e` and concat the string:

```
$_ = 'int blah() { return 5; }';
s/int\s*blah\(\)\s*\{\s*return\s*([3-9]);\s*}/'int blah() { return '.$1+1 . '; }'/eg;
print;
```

Comment: This answer assumes that the number is less than 10.

Comment: How do I add one to the return value? I know how to match it, just not how to add one.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e 'use Tie::File;tie @array,'Tie::File',$ARGV[0] || die;s|(return\s+)(\d+)(.*)|$2>1?$1.($2+1).$3:$1.$2.$3|e for (@array);untie @array;' FILENAME
```